# Java - Windows 7 reading files and write them to a List

Tags: java, windows, file, list

Basically, what I wanna do is to read all files from a specific path of my windows machine e.g. "C:\". After reading all files to an file array, I check within the for-loop if a file is a directory or not. I'm also filtering out hidden files. After that I sort each of the 2 array lists, if the current directory is not the root directory the "../" is added and everything is written to the final array lists.

But the problem is - this java program shows me more directories than there are, I think. Because the output of the windows cmd shell for "C:\> dir" is not the same as the output of my java program.

Any ideas how to fix that?

**Output of "C:\> dir":**

```
{ "PerfLogs", "Program Files", "Program Files(x86)", "Users", "Windows" }
```

**Output of this java program:**

```
{ "Documents and Settings", "Dokumente und Einstellungen", "PerfLogs", "Program Files(x86)", "Program Files", "Users", "Windows", "pagefile.sys" }
```

---

```
private void getFileBrowser(String dirPATH) {
    ITEM_TEMP = new ArrayList<String>();
    PATH_TEMP = new ArrayList<String>();
    ITEM_TEMP.clear();
    PATH_TEMP.clear();

    currentWorkingDirectory = dirPATH;

    File f = new File(dirPATH);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];

        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            if(!file.isHidden() & !file.getName().startsWith("$")) {
                PATH_TEMP.add(file.getPath());
                ITEM_TEMP.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!file.isHidden()) {
                PATH_TEMP.add(file.getPath());
                ITEM_TEMP.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(ITEM_TEMP);
    Collections.sort(PATH_TEMP);

    ITEM.clear();
    PATH.clear();

    if(!dirPATH.equals(rootDirectory)) {
        ITEM.add("../");
        PATH.add(f.getParent());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < ITEM_TEMP.size(); i++) {
        ITEM.add(ITEM_TEMP.get(i));
    }
    for(int i=0; i < PATH_TEMP.size(); i++) {
        PATH.add(PATH_TEMP.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Java code is printing out every file (pagefile.sys should be hidden by default on your system). You said that you want to filter out hidden files.

The problem lies probably in this line:

```
 if(!file.isHidden() & !file.getName().startsWith("$"))
```

& is a bitwise AND operator, you should use && -logical AND operator.

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a JAVA-way to get only the files/directories which are shown by the cmd "dir" command? Or should I use the runtime to pick the directories out?

Comment: There are two ways. Use directly the dir command by executing it from Java with `exec` command (see here http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8 ) or... learn what kind of files/directories `dir` shows and fix your code to do that. When you fix your error with `&` you will probably be quite close to the solution-dir by default doesn't print hidden files. I'm not sure if the statement with `startsWith("$")` is necessary. You could probably read dir help by executing `dir /?`-maybe it will help you further.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't matter if I use "&" or "&&" - no other result. Maybe I'll try the runtime way later. PS: The "startsWith("$")" command is needed to filter out some folders of the "Windows" directory. They don't disappear with "isHidden()"..